# How to read URL with read.csv.sql in R

Tags: r, url, sqldf

I'm trying to import a csv document from a URL using the `read.csv.sql {sqldf}` but without success so far.

I tried the following but seems **"file" is not recognized**.

Any help?

```
read.csv.sql("https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/AirPassengers.csv", "select * from file")
```

Comment: Do you have to use `sqldf`? As `read.csv("https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/AirPassengers.csv")` will work too

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `read.csv.sql` doesn't support `https:`, the help page `?read.csv.sql` says:

> file: A file path or a URL (beginning with http:// or ftp://)

You can try the `http` version of the file:

```
library(sqldf)
read.csv.sql("http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/AirPassengers.csv", 
             "select * from file")

#        X     time AirPassengers
#1     "1" 1949.000           112
#2     "2" 1949.083           118
#3     "3" 1949.167           132
#4     "4" 1949.250           129
#5     "5" 1949.333           121
#6     "6" 1949.417           135
# ...
```

Comment: You may also need `eol = "\n"` if the end of line differs from your OS's default.  Note that `sql="select * from file"` is the default so if that is what you want then it  could be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `read.csv` directly on the url

```
read.csv("https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/AirPassengers.csv")
      X     time AirPassengers
1     1 1949.000           112
2     2 1949.083           118
3     3 1949.167           132
4     4 1949.250           129
5     5 1949.333           121
6     6 1949.417           135
```